# Calculating the rotation angle to follow a line in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I have a random line being drawn, and I want to trace along the line with a Letter, V in this case.  I would like the bottom point of the V to rotate and follow the direction of the line no matter what angle or direction the line is drawn. But I'm honestly at a loss for how to calculate that angle.  Below is some bare bones code to demonstrate my problem. You'll see the Red line being drawn, and I would like the V's bottom point to lead the line being drawn.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
float [ ] lineProgress = { 75, 350, 350, 350, 0 };
int lineSpeed = 25;
float angle = 0;

void setup() {
  background (255);
  size(400,400);
  noFill();
  frameRate(5);
}

void draw() 
{
    background (255);
    strokeWeight(1);

    stroke (0,255,0);
    line(lineProgress[0],lineProgress[1],lineProgress[2],lineProgress[3]);

    stroke (255,0,0);

    fill(255, 0,0, 125);

    float angle;
    //How Do I calculate this based on the line being drawn?
    angle =radians(270);

     line(
         lineProgress[0]
         , lineProgress[1]
         , lerp(lineProgress[0], lineProgress[2],lineProgress[4]/lineSpeed)
         , lerp(lineProgress[1], lineProgress[3],lineProgress[4]/lineSpeed)

         );

    rotLetter(
              "V"
               , lerp(lineProgress[0]
               , lineProgress[2]
               , lineProgress[4]/lineSpeed)
               , lerp(lineProgress[1]
               , lineProgress[3],lineProgress[4]/lineSpeed)
               , angle
               ) ;

     rotLetter("V", 200,200,angle) ;               

     lineProgress[4]++;
     if (lineProgress[4]>lineSpeed)
     {
       lineProgress[4]=0;
       lineProgress[0]=random(50,350);
       lineProgress[1]=random(50,350);
       lineProgress[2]=random(50,350);
       lineProgress[3]=random(50,350);
     }

}

void rotLetter(String l, float x, float y, float ang) {
  pushMatrix(); // save state
  textAlign(CENTER); // center letter horiz
  translate(x, y); // move to position
  rotate(ang); // rotate
   // draw char centered on acsender
   // this will work for most Caps, and some lc letters
   // but it will not allways vert center letters
  text(l, 0, textAscent()/2);
  popMatrix(); // return to saved coordinate matrix
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a line from `(x0, y0)` to `(x1, y1)` with X offset `dx = x1 - x0` and Y offset `dy = y1 - y0`, the angle is:

```
atan2(dy, dx)
```

which will be measured in radians.

Using [`atan2(y, x)`](http://www.processing.org/reference/atan2_.html) instead of `atan(y / x)` ensures that the angle returned is in the right quadrant.  `atan` only returns results from `-π/2` to `+π/2`, rather than the full `-π` to `+π`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the slope of line `y = mx + c` (`m` being the slope). Angle = `arctan(m)`.
2. Angle to rotate (clockwise) = `2 * Pi - Angle`

Answer (score 0):

Your friend in calculating the rotation angle is the [sine/cosine relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent). You can use any of them, but the tangent one doesn't involve calculating the length of the hypotenuse:

```
tan A = a / b
```

so your angle would be

```
A = arctan( a / b )
```

or in Java terms:

```
double angle = Math.atan( ( lineprogress[ 3 ] - lineprogress[ 1 ] ) / 
                          ( lineprogress[ 2 ] - lineprogress[ 0 ] ) );
```

or as @Alnitak also writes, use atan2 to obtain results in the right quadrant:

```
double angle =  Math.atan2( lineprogress[ 2 ] - lineprogress[ 0 ] ,
                            lineprogress[ 3 ] - lineprogress[ 1 ] );
```

assuming that (x1,y1) == ( lineprogress[ 0 ] , lineprogress[ 1 ] ) and congruently for (x2,y2)

Cheers,